# How to pass information from one adapter to other?

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, interface, navigation, sharedpreferences

i have two adapters one for my card view and the other one for my drawer. The cards contains links to other options in the app and the drawer contains the same options. What i want is when user clicks on the card, the options in the drawer menu should get selected. Here is my code.

Drawer Adapter:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "ConstantConditions"})
public class DrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<DrawerItem> items;
    private Map<Class<? extends DrawerItem>, Integer> viewTypes;
    private SparseArray<DrawerItem> holderFactories;

    private   OnItemSelectedListener listener;

    public DrawerAdapter(List<DrawerItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.viewTypes = new HashMap<>();
        this.holderFactories = new SparseArray<>();

        processViewTypes();
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ViewHolder holder = holderFactories.get(viewType).createViewHolder(parent);
        holder.adapter = this;
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        items.get(position).bindViewHolder(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return viewTypes.get(items.get(position).getClass());
    }

    private void processViewTypes() {
        int type = 0;
        for (DrawerItem item : items) {
            if (!viewTypes.containsKey(item.getClass())) {
                viewTypes.put(item.getClass(), type);
                holderFactories.put(type, item);
                type++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setSelected(int position) {
        DrawerItem newChecked = items.get(position);
        if (!newChecked.isSelectable()) {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            DrawerItem item = items.get(i);
            if (item.isChecked()) {
                item.setChecked(false);
                notifyItemChanged(i);
                break;
            }
        }

        newChecked.setChecked(true);
        notifyItemChanged(position);

        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    public void setListener(OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    static abstract class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private DrawerAdapter adapter;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.setSelected(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
        void onItemSelected(int position);
    }


}
```

Card Adapter:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
    ;
    private RecyclerView parentRecycler;
    private List<Card> data;

    public CardAdapter(List<Card> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        parentRecycler = recyclerView;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Card card = data.get(position);
        holder.getAdapterPosition();
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .asGif()
                .load(card.getCardIcon())


                .into(holder.gifImageView);
        holder.textView.setText(card.getCardName());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }




    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private GifImageView gifImageView;
        private TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            gifImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_gif);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_name);

            itemView.findViewById(R.id.container).setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void showText() {
            int parentHeight = ((View) gifImageView.getParent()).getHeight();
            float scale = (parentHeight - textView.getHeight()) / (float) gifImageView.getHeight();
            gifImageView.setPivotX(gifImageView.getWidth() * 0.5f);
            gifImageView.setPivotY(0);
            gifImageView.animate().scaleX(scale)
                    .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          //  gifImageView.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
                        }
                    })
                    .scaleY(scale).setDuration(200)
                    .start();
        }

        public void hideText() {
            textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            gifImageView.animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f)
                .setDuration(200)
                .start();
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { parentRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(getAdapterPosition());
          }


                   }
            }
        }
```

P.S: I am new to programming any kind of help is appreciated.[As you can see in the image below that I have cards in the main view and the same options are in the drawer menu for example question papers. Now when the user clicks on question paper in the main view the question paper in drawer menu should get selected.[][1]][1]

thank you!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FooVb.jpg